# antlr4 missing file Python3LexerBase.go

Tags: python, go, antlr4

guys I need to analysis python by golang with antlr4,I found Python3LexerBase.go is missing,Does anyone have it？danke

Comment: Missing from where? Which grammar are you using? I don't think there's a Python3 grammar for Go in the grammars-v4 repository at least.

Comment: @rickdamon I just checked the main branch in the [antlr source](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/tool/resources/org/antlr/v4/tool/templates/codegen/Go/Go.stg#L1426). The bug is still there, and although [a fix is available](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/pull/3284/commits/e5df6ab3fc4f537e8affcb0184231b8584e0f9ac), it's likely it won't ever be integrated. Super classing for the Python3 grammar for Go will not work for the lexer. You can implement the base class for Python3 in Go, but you will need to change your local copy of the runtime as well. I usually mod the source in GOPATH.

Answer (score 1):

That file is not provided in the [Github repo of grammars](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4). You'll need to implement that class yourself. You can look at the other implementations that *are* provided of the `Python3LexerBase` class (C#, Java and Python are provided, if memory serves me well).

Also see: https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/issues/2288

Please note that the [Github repo of grammars](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4) is not an official maintained repository of the authors/maintainers of ANTLR. It is a large amount of (not too well tested) contributions of other people. Do not expect all files to be there, and be cautious when using them in anything other than a small side/pet project you're working on.

Comment: Antlr 4.9.2 Go target does not generate correct code when superClass of a lexer is used--at all. The generated code crashes if you try. See [the issued I raised](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/3254). Therefore, the [Python3 grammar](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/python/python3) can't run in Go. I am not sure if this will be fixed for Antlr 4.9.3. But, this is why some of the grammars in grammars-v4 for other targets haven't been implemented yet.

Comment: Good to know @kaby76